# Visual Studio Code with broken Auto Imports

Tags: angular, import, autocomplete, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code I am having often Issues with the Auto-Import Feature while working on AngularJS. The Auto-Import is working, but it's importing wrong classes.

eg. typing...

```
RouterModule.forRoot..
```

VSC is auto-importing...

```
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router/src/router_module";
```

But his leads to the error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/router/src/router_module'
```

The right import should be:

```
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I prevent VSC from importing the wrong classes?

Comment: Are you using some auto import plugin?

Comment: I am but in this setting all plugins are disabled. So the origin shouldn't be from the auto import plugins.

Comment: seems like a recurring bug tracked https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19694

Comment: ah thank you for this link. It really looks like a bug -.- . Thank you for posting this.